# Can we give aura:id attribute for plain html elements?

Tags: lightning

Can I rely on assigning `aura:id` attribute for plain html elements like `div` and accessing these elements in controller with the syntax `component.find('div-aura-id')`? Because I don't see any documentation saying we can give `aura:id` attributes to plain html elements.

This approach is perfectly working and below is a simple example.

**Component.cmp**:

```
<aura:component>
    <div aura:id="div-aura-id" id="div-id"></div>
    <button onclick="{!c.buttonClick}">click me</button>
</aura:component>
```

**ComponentController.js**:

```
// Controller
({
    buttonClick: function(component,event,helper){
        //This is printing div-id as expected.
        console.log(component.find('div-aura-id').getElement().id);
    }
})
```

Where is this documented saying that we can assign `aura:id` attribute to plain html elements? I don't see here ([Component IDs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm))

I have been accessing these elements until now as `document.getElementById('div-id')` but I ran into few issues(will post a separate question on that soon.) so I am starting think if the above approach is recommended?

Comment: When I write the same code on doInit aura:handler rather than button click, doesn't work

Comment: @MonalisaDas Can you post sample code on a separate question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [HTML in Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_html.htm) documentation says it:

> An HTML tag is treated as a first-class component by the framework.
>   Each HTML tag is translated into an  component, *allowing it
>   to enjoy the same rights and privileges as any other component*.
>
> For
>   example, the framework automatically converts a standard HTML **<div>**
>   tag to this component:
>
> **<aura:html tag="div" />**

in the italics line. (I added the italics and bold.)

Just had a quick search in some components we've created and maybe 10% of the `aura:id` are on HTML elements. No problems so far...

The handling of HTML tags can be seen in action by using your browsers "Sources" tab. For example, this piece of component markup:

```
<button aura:id="save" class="slds-button onclick="{! c.ok }">OK</button>
```

gets translated to this definition in the resulting component JavaScript:

```
{  
  "componentDef":{  
    "descriptor":"markup://aura:html"
  },
  "localId":"save",
  "attributes":{  
    "values":{  
      "HTMLAttributes":{  
        "descriptor":"HTMLAttributes",
        "value":{  
          "class":"slds-button",
          "onclick":"{!c.ok}"
        }
      },
      "tag":{  
        "descriptor":"tag",
        "value":"button"
      },
      "body":{  
        "descriptor":"body",
        "value":[  
          {  
            "componentDef":{  
              "descriptor":"markup://aura:text"
            },
            "attributes":{  
              "values":{  
                "value":{  
                  "descriptor":"value",
                  "value":"OK"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The framework translates all these component JavaScript definitions into HTML in the browser, so it makes some sense to treat the HTML elements much like the (more complex) component elements.